# Динамические стили className

Tags: reactjs

Есть подобный JSX код, как только он рендерится в браузер и я жму на кнопку чтобы изменить darkTheme, то в самом html значения не меняются, каким образом я могу изменить className, что я мог динамически менять его значения и ререндерить в html

```
const reverseTheme = () => {
    darkTheme === true
      ? darkTheme = false
      : darkTheme = true
  };

    <span className={darkTheme}>...</span>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скорее всего, где-то выше объявляется стейт:

```
const [darkTheme, setDarkTheme] = useState(false)
```

Нужно не изменять значение переменной напрямую, а устанавливать новое значение стейта:

```
const reverseTheme = () => setDarkTheme(prev => !prev)
```